# Своя надпись для пустой TableView в JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Если таблица пустая, то выходится надпись: «No content in table». Как переопределить эту надпись?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо забрать проперти с именем [placeholder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#placeholderProperty) и проставить свое значение в полученную Node ( по умолчанию placeholder - это Label, т.е. вы можете скастить к Label и вызвать метод setText('my placeholder') )

Comment: Если не сложно можете в примере показать

Comment: `table.setPlaceholder( new Text( "my placeholder" ) );`

Comment: Вориан, опиванный в ответе( может он правильнее ): `Node node = table.getPlaceholder(); if ( node instanceof Labeled ) { ((Labeled)node).setText( "my placeholder" ); }`